# Update the ColumnNo field to display the same number when the AppID and FootNote are the same

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to update the ColumnNo field to display the same number when the AppID and FootNote are the same. I need it to display like the first image below.

[image: Bad Data]

I have tried

```
ROW_NUMBER() Over (partition by AppID, FootNote Order by AppID) as RowNum
```

Which works in reverse.

[image: What I Need]

And some other functions to no avail. How can I flip this?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: As per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: I don't get the logic of the numbering?

Comment: This was a simple question that was answered in under 5 minutes... in the future lets not go overboard with complaining about the formatting of the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dense_rank()`:

```
row_number() Over (order by AppID, FootNote) as RowNum
```

Comment: Dense_rank() Over (partition by AppID Order by AppID, FootNote)

Comment: Yes I was using this wrong before, thanks